# Can OS X connect to BLE device using Mac's onboard adapter?

Tags: macos, serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy

With Bluetooth 2, when you Pair from OS X (using Mac's built-in bluetooth hardware) to an external BT device, you see a serial com port with names like dev/cu.HC-05-DevB / tty.HC-05_DevB -- because BT 2 enables SPP service, usable by the Mac's built-in BT adapter. Serial-capable programs, for me mostly Arduino IDE and Processing, can use that port for serial comm to the external device. Similar situation using Windows.

But if you want both PC/Mac and phone apps to comm serially with the device, you're going to want a BLE connection. And, so far, I've found no way on either Windows or OS X, to make a serial COM port using their built-in BLE adapter -- e.g. to comm with device like an HM-10 module on an Arduino. Of course, various phone apps can make 2 way comm with the HM-10 module attached to Arduino. But if you also want the PC/Mac to be able to connect, it's not so simple.

I can use an app like LightBlue on the Mac to read/write bytes via built-in BLE, talking to an HM-10 module mounted to the Arduino. But this cumbersome interface is only useful for testing, not comparable to the GUI I get with Processing. And if I use a USB-TTL serial dongle on the Mac, wired to a second HM-10 module (in central ROLE), then the 2 modules can connect and should be able to have 2 way comm. But in many tries, many module configurations, with various serial devices (microprocessors and USB-TTL dongles), I can only get peripheral to central comm -- never got the central HM-10 to send to the peripheral. Even if I could make 2 way comm like this, I'd rather not have these extra 2 devices in the way. Isn't it possible to use the PC/Mac's onboard BLE hardware for a serial port that can be used by regular programs ?

My interim solution uses a dual-mode BT2/BLE module (H3 or HM-12) on the Arduino, then on the PC or Mac, using SPP, pair with the module's BT 2 port. For various iPhone apps, I can use the module's BLE mode for comm to the Arduino -- only one of the modes is usable at a time, of course. This works, but seems more complicated than it needs to be.

[The poster of this question [How do I read Bluetooth Low Energy transmitted data programmatically on Mac OS X 10.9.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388308/) was advised to use the 'noble' Node.js module, but since I've no experience with Xcode or Node.js, was hoping to find simpler solution.]